# Integrating $\frac{x+1}x$

Tags: integration, logarithms

A textbook way to integrate $\frac{a}{x}$ is $\int \frac{a}{x} dx = a\ln(x) $

However the answer to the question $\int \frac{x+1}{x} dx$

is not $(x+1)\ln(x)$

but is rather $\frac{x}{x} + \frac{1}{x} = 1 + ln(x) $

I see the logic of the latter answer but I don't understand why the former is wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your doubt seems to come from the fact that you apparently think that $$\int\frac{x+1}xdx=(x+1)\int\frac{dx}x=(x+1)\log x$$ which is completely wrong, of course.

Comment: $a$ is a constant, not a function of $x$. You can't treat a function of $x$, such as $x+1$, or anything involving $x$, as a constant.

Comment: Also, the answer is $x+\ln\vert x\vert+C$, not $1+\ln(x)$.

Comment: thanks for all your helpful comments. The answer is listed as 1+ln|x|+C but might be a typo as your answer makes much more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former is wrong because your way of integrating $a/x$ works (in general) **only if** $a$ does not depend on $x$. Since $x+1$ does depend on $x$, you can not use this rule.

An analogy: For a constant $a$, we have $\int a\, \mathrm dx = a x + C$. However, we don’t have $\int \dfrac1x\, \mathrm dx = 1 + C$.

Comment: Cheers! That makes much more sense